# Observe change in Published property within an array using Combine

Tags: swift, combine

I've got existing code where a `UITableView` monitors changes to its data source using a delegate (in order to react to taps on section headers to expand / collapse rows).

I'd like to use Combine instead use a subscriber and monitor changes to the data source. The data source is an array, where I'd like to monitor changes to a property of a class. So:

```
public class SectionViewModel: ObservableObject, Identifiable, Equatable {
  public static func == (lhs: SectionViewModel, rhs: SectionViewModel) -> Bool {
    return lhs.id == rhs.id
  }

  public var id: Int = 0

  @Published var isExpanded = true

  public init(id: Int, isExpanded: Bool = true) {
    self.id = id
    self.isExpanded = isExpanded
  }
}

// Data source
var models = [
  SectionViewModel(id: 0, isExpanded: true),
  SectionViewModel(id: 1, isExpanded: true),
  SectionViewModel(id: 2, isExpanded: true),
  SectionViewModel(id: 3, isExpanded: true),
]
```

The model is passed to each of the `UITableViewHeaderFooterView`s which would then toggle `isExpanded` when tapped. Do I need to create and maintain an array of subscribers (via `sink`) and cancel them as and when the contents of the array change? Would the following be the correct approach?

```
let allModelSubscription = models.map { model in
  model.$isExpanded.sink { (expanded) in
    print("Model changed: \(model.id)")
  }
}
```

This works but I understandably get bombarded with published changes when the view controller loads the first time. How can I avoid that?

Comment: I’m not sure what the best practice is - want to make sure this is how it’s done, plus not sure how to avoid the initially published changes from reaching the downstream. Sorry, my first day with Combine, in fact my first hour of trying to use it.

Comment: I want to observe changes to both the model and the Published property inside of the model class, so that I can react if the expansion state changes as well as when the model itself changes. I could arguably use a Diffable data source from iOS 13 - need to look into that next. But right now I want to be able to bind / react to the published property that the section headers change. Not sure I understand how the mutable array is a poor choice of model though.

Comment: Fair enough, although I should add this is more of a Meta Model representation for the section to be able to use, while using the same to represent its state for convenience. I should probably turn other properties immutable however I’d like to keep `isExpanded` a published, mutable property in order to observe state changes. Is that a bad idea?

Comment: It seems `@Published` properties can only be defined as part of a `class` - so by convention the model needs to be mutable. Is that not how binding would work between the view controller and the view?

Answer (score 0):

It is not clear all your dependencies, but try the following

```
@Published var isExpanded: Bool   // << only declaration

public init(id: Int, isExpanded: Bool = true) {
   self.id = id
   _isExpanded = Published(initialValue: isExpanded) // << explicit
}
```